# IIS URL rewrite trouble with CSS url() values

Tags: javascript, css, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

A week or so ago I asked a question regarding running 2 different app/web servers on a VPS, but using one main incoming URL/port (using only site.com and not needing site.com:8080).

I received an answer and have for the most part made the solution work. I needed to use URL Rewriting, and in doing so make both inbound and outbound rules for the rewrite.

This works perfect EXCEPT when I have a CSS property with a value URL being relative. For example:

```
.rule{
    background-image: url(/images/picture.jpg);
}
```

My current inbound and outbound rules are as follows

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="java/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://s17857763.onlinehome-server.com:8080/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="RewriteRelative" preCondition="IsHtml" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/java/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteAbsolute" preCondition="IsHtml" enabled="false">
                <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="http(s)?://s17857763\.com/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/java/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsHtml">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*/java/.*" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

If you would like to see the issue i'm having, with your dev console open, go to http://s17857763.onlinehome-server.com/java/FirstMaven/

Because of the outbound rules it loads the normal CSS and JS links fine because they come from HTML tags....but i dont know if it's possible to fix the CSS url( ) path.

Comment: The URL for your issue isn't working.

Comment: Sorry about that Chrissi, it should work now. I forgot the "s" before the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot about quotation marks

Try this

```
.rule{
    background-image: url("/images/picture.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your issue is going to be the preCondition rules. You're limiting it to only be HTML. For CSS, you either want to add preconditions for "^text/css" and another for "^application/javascript" or remove the precondition altogether. I'd lean towards doing the first option. It allows finer grained control. I'm working on the same thing right now, which is how I found this page. If I figure it out, I'll post what I did here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have the CSS rewriting done and working. In preconditions, I added the following:

```
<preCondition name="IsCSS">
    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^/text/css" />
</preCondition>
```

Then, in my outBoundRules section, I added the following:

```
<rule name="RewriteCSSRelativePaths" preCondition="IsCSS">
    <match filterByTags="None" pattern="url\(&apos;" />
    <action type="Rewrite"  value="url(&apos;/<path>/" />
</rule>
```

My pattern is only looking for **url('** . If you want more control than that, adjust the pattern to look for accordingly. Note the ( in my pattern. I had to escape the ( because () in regex capture data, which I didn't want to do. In my case, I just wanted to adjust the path to go through our software proxy.